# Using Oracle with Perl

Tags: oracle, perl

I've been trying to install the perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64.rpm package all day. It keeps giving me the below error:

```
perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 from /perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libnnz10.so()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-    1.el5.x86_64 (/perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64)
perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 from /perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libocci.so.10.1()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 (/perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64)
perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 from /perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libocijdbc10.so()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 (/perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64)
perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 from /perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libclntsh.so.10.1()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 (/perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64)
perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 from /perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libociei.so()(64bit) is needed by package perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64 (/perl-DBD-Oracle-1.19-1.el5.x86_64)
```

As far as I know I have all the correct libraries installed, ie

```
oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.5-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient-devel-10.2.0.5-1.x86_64.rpm
oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-10.2.0.5-1.x86_64.rpm
perl-DBI-1.52-2.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

and all of the files it complains are missing are installed, eg the first dependency it claims is missing is libnnz10.so but this is installed in /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib/libnnz10.so. Also if I ask yum to resolve this dependency then it does, eg

```
> yum provides */libnnz10.so
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.5-1.x86_64 : Instant Client for Oracle Database 10g
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib/libnnz10.so
```

I have set the variable of

```
ORACLE_HOME="/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib"
```

I have also added the lib dir above to the path.

So why does yum say that it can resolve it but then says it can't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Oracle/) is one of the most notoriously difficult well-known CPAN modules to install. I've installed many CPAN modules over the last decade and every time I have to install [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Oracle/) I take a sharp intake of breath and prepare for hours of pain.

I recently installed [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Oracle/) on a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS desktop. Let me see if I can remember what I did.

From the Oracle site I downloaded:

- instantclient-basic-linux.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip
- instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip
- instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip

I made a directory `/usr/local/oracle`, changed to that directory, and unzipped all three files.

Then I ran:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_11_2 \
  ORACLE_HOME=/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_11_2 \
  cpan DBD::Oracle
```

I might have left something out. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to work. I set up a fresh VM to try it. When I run cpan it says it cannot determine my oracle version. I have included an extra step I believe is required which is to create 2 symlinks for libclntsh.so and libocci.so

Comment: @MikeKulls it is unfortunate that there is a lightweight Oracle adapter for Java now that you can throw into a jar for portable Oracle programs - but that Perl doesn't have an easy method to access Oracle without having to compile in native libraries.

Comment: I'm thinking the solution is to abandon Perl and go with Java anyway. Perl is a dogs breakfast really. Its only redeeming feature is regular expressions which I presume Java can do anyway. I would actually like to use C# but it doesn't really do Linux, at least not in a supported way.

Comment: @MikeKulls I like Perl a lot - it is far more flexible than Java when you have a lightweight job to do; and scripts can be modified without a recompile needed. It is Oracle that is the dogs' breakfast.

Comment: I can't really comment on Java as I haven't used it much but my jobs are not really light weight and compiling is an advantage imo. It stops people stuffing around with my work and making 'simple' changes that I don't know about and accidentally overwrite later on. I really like C# and I know it's largely a copy of Java. I just find with Perl you end up relying on some poorly documented module written by someone in their garage.

Comment: @MikeKulls Perl has **compiled to bytecode**, since at least 1994. Which was **before Java** was released. The main difference is Perl is so **fast at compiling** that it compiles everything, every time that you run it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can be installed on newer versions of Red Hat. We put 6.4 on a VM and everything installed fine so it looks like that is sort of an answer.